# Azure WebApp Outbound Ports

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I understand that Web Apps are restricted to ports 80/443 for inbound requests, however what about outbound?  For example if I were to deploy an application that made a call to some third part service on a random port, e.g. 8085, would it be allowed?  If so, is there a way to restrict the ip addresses and/or ports that outbound requests can be made on?

Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Azure Web Apps, the restriction is only for inbound requests. There is no restriction on Outbound IP addresses and ports.

Out of the box, Azure Web Apps will only allow you to put restrictions on incoming requests using DIPR http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/12/09/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/. There is no mechanism to restrict Outbound.